# How to solve Firebase onAuthStateChanged firing 2x (initialization and resolution)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been unable to find a strong solution to this issue. The issue being that `onAuthStateChanged` will execute once when it initializes, and once again when it resolves. Since my apps loads views depending on auth state, the initialization always returns an undependable value.

Is there a strong solution to this yet? Or is this a non-issue and I'm just crazy?

I've looked quite a bit and have only found hacks or workarounds.

A couple:

[Firebase Android onAuthStateChanged called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673616/firebase-android-onauthstatechanged-called-twice)

[Possible to check Firebase 3 auth state synchronously in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059900/possible-to-check-firebase-3-auth-state-synchronously-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The onAuthStateChanged will always trigger on initialization. However, it should not fire again unless there is a change in the current Firebase Id token (sign out or new sign in event). However, keep in mind that firebase Id tokens are refreshed every hour or so, so this will trigger constantly every hour when the token is refreshed. You can add logic in the listener to check if the user has changed and ignore if the same user is still logged in. If you notice any other behavior, please notify the Firebase teams to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps my language is not precise enough. onAuthStateChanged always executes the callback twice on initialization. First it initializes, returns `null` immediately and executes the given callback. It then resolves, returning the correct value from Firebase and then again executes the given callback.

Comment: Does this happen immediately? I already mentioned the token refreshes every hour or so. Also calling getToken(true) will force a refresh.

Comment: I've been seeing this issue too, and it was immediate. I believe though that it might be due to the use of both onAuthStateChanged and also the use of signInWith, both triggering it to call twice. Perhaps that is the issue?